# How do I work out how many days ago date1 was compared to date2, using datejs?

Tags: datejs

```
var d1 = Date.parse(date); // eg, 7th jan
var d2 = Date.today(); // eg, 2nd jan
```

I want to do:

```
(d2 - d1).days
```

which with the above data, should return 5.

Is this possible with datejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional **TimeSpan** module includes functionality to easily get various value differences between two date objects.

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/time.js

Just include after your main date.js include, or combine.

In the "time.js" file, there's also a **TimePeriod** class. You might not require, so just crop what you need if weight is an issue.

The following sample demonstrates the full scenario.

**Example**

```
var d1 = Date.parse("jan 7"); // eg, 7th jan
var d2 = Date.parse("jan 2"); // eg, 2nd jan

console.log(new TimeSpan(d1 - d2).days); // 5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, I used the Timespan library but altered it to support TotalHours etc.